# C++ precise measure time in decimal ms

Tags: c++, time, decimal, measure

I am measuring time of sorting algorhytms like Bubble,Insert, Selection and Quick sort.
I am using this for my purpose

```
    long int before = GetTickCount();
    QuickSort(pole,0,dlzka-1);
    long int after = GetTickCount();
    double dif = double((after - before));
cout << "Quick Sort with time "<< dif << " ms " << endl;
```

I am sorting array with 30 000 integers and working fine for other sort except the QuickSort which is probbably so fast that it sorts 30k integers in less then 1ms and then my timeer says it is 0ms which look like a mistake.
I want to write it for example 0,01ms just to make it looks that it run corectly.
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you benchmark, you never benchmark just *one* run. Your timer is not precise/accurate enough to give meaningful results across that tiny amount of time.

For example, [the documentation for `GetTickCount`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says:

> The resolution of the GetTickCount function is limited to the resolution of the system timer, which is typically in the range of 10 milliseconds to 16 milliseconds.

So, it is plainly obvious that obtaining a value of *0.01ms* is folly.

**Instead, benchmark *many* runs, then divide by the number of times you ran it.**

Answer (score 4):

Put your code into a loop that you run 1000 times, with the clock started and stopped outside of that loop. Then divide the result by 1000. Or, if you like, the result of the clock will now be in µs instead of in ms.

If your loop is very fast, you may need more than 1000 repetitions to get a meaningful measurement. You could run 10,000, 100,000, ... etc times until you get a "reasonable number of milliseconds".

When the piece of code you are testing is very fast, the overhead of the loop may become significant; in that case, you might run an "empty loop" and subtract the two results to give you the "net" timing of the inner part of the loop only.

It is rare, however, that this is something you need to do - most often you are trying to compare different algorithms, and as long as the overhead of the loop is the same it doesn't matter that it exists - the faster algorithm will still be faster.

**One more thought - and this is pretty important:** if you sort things in the first pass through the loop, and your algorithm speed depends on whether the data is sorted or not, you will get a different answer for multiple passes than you get for a single pass. Thus you need to make sure that you are using the same inputs for every pass through the algorithm. This might mean that you cannot use in-place sorting, or that you copy the unsorted data back into the "to be sorted" array at every pass of the algorithm.

**other option:** there is a [good article on high precision timing](http://www.guyrutenberg.com/2007/09/22/profiling-code-using-clock_gettime/) that explains the use of the `clock_gettime()` function, with its various options and flavors. On some systems this will allow you to use higher resolution measurements. It is still always a good idea to do multiple runs, or even multiple runs of multiple runs - so you can compute statistics and thus come up with a confidence interval.

Comment: Pray tell, what is this "us" unit of which you speak?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Besides being too obvious, there are books and applications that uses `us` instead of `µs`.

Comment: What if running the code 1000 times takes less than one tick?

Comment: Then you run 1,000,000 times... and your result will be in ns/loop. You don't start off running a ton of times until you know roughly what timing to expect, then you tune the measurement to give you the desired precision. Note - when the time gets very short, you will want to run an "empty" timing loop as well to subtract the 'overhead'.

Comment: Maybe you could use that information to make the answer more useful.

Comment: @Floris: unfortunately measuring the time spent in an empty loop is much harder than it seems. If you measure in Debug mode, well the measure is pointless, and if you measure with optimizations on (Release mode), then the compiler is likely to remove the empty loop entirely.

Comment: @MatthieuM. - I know that an empty loop usually gets "optimized out" with higher levels of optimization; I should have mentioned that you have to do "something 'useful'" in the loop to keep the compiler from skipping it altogether. Do you have any favorite methods? I find that keeping a running sum of the loop counter is usually enough - as long as you appear to do something with the result afterwards (again, if you don't use the result, an optimizing compiler will optimize it out). `if(runningSum>0) printf("the loop took %.3fms\n", loopTime);` would take care of that.

Comment: @Floris the compiler can just precompute the whole loop (not at all unlikely). Or, if all you do with it is `runningSum > 0`, it can instead just infer that `runningSum` will never be negative or zero and skip it entirely (not at all unlikely either).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit They are, but I do not have `µ` on my keyboard. Hence `u`.

Comment: @BJobnh I don't have µ on my keyboard either :P

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - yes, but don't you think it is a well enough known abbreviation? Just like uF, uCi, etc. See [ISO 2955-1983](http://isotc.iso.org/livelink/livelink/4289384/ISO_2955-1983E_repr_of_SI_units_with_limited_char_sets.pdf?func=doc.Fetch&nodeid=4289384) which states (table 2) that `u` is an acceptable abbreviation when only Latin characters are available. As is the case on my keyboard (yes, I can "look" for the µ -- it's option-m on my Mac -- but in daily use I don't bother. And neither do my colleagues. So it has become "common practice".

Comment: @Floris, FWIW, if you are curious, this is my current favourite "method": https://github.com/rmartinho/nonius/blob/devel/include/nonius/detail/estimate_clock.h%2B%2B (not that I'm an expert in this sort of thing; I just developed some morbid curiosity recently)

Comment: `&mu;` is not hard to type.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes - yes, I realize that compilers can be "too clever" for this simplistic estimate of overhead to work; do you have a suggestion for how to fool them into telling you what the loop overhead is? Is there a switch (`#pragma`?) that says "turn off optimization for the next bit"?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - I never thought of that... sometimes I have such glaring blind spots it's quite embarrassing! Thanks.

Comment: @Floris I assign the results of repeatedly getting the current time into a `volatile` variable (see my "empty" loop here: https://github.com/rmartinho/nonius/blob/devel/include/nonius/detail/estimate_clock.h%2B%2B#L76). Though there I'm interested in the actual cost of calling the "current time" function. If you want a completely empty loop you could assign 0 to a volatile variable in a loop, I guess, but I don't see how that would produce results meaningful for any purpose at all.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes - interesting link. I will have to take a closer look at that code. Not sure I understand why `volatile auto ignored = Clock::now(); (void)ignore;` would not be optimized out...

Comment: @Floris: this is the semantic of `volatile`, actually. `volatile` tells the compiler: do not optimize out reads or writes to this variable, for it used to communicate (back and forth) with the hardware.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I did know that `volatile` means "don't assume you know the value of this variable ahead of time", but I didn't realize that assigning the result of a function call to a volatile variable could not be optimized out. But now that I think of it, if the `volatile` variable points to a hardware register that's precisely what it needs to do. Thanks for clearing that up for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using c++11:

`std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` represents the clock with the smallest tick period provided by the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If your compiler supports C++11 with [std::chrono](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono), this is best way to measure time at high accuracy; it is cross-platform and part of the standard library.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

::std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point startTime = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
doWork();
::std::chrono::steady_clock::duration elapsedTime = ::std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - startTime;
std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(9) << std::endl;
double duration = ::std::chrono::duration_cast< ::std::chrono::duration< double > >(elapsedTime).count();
std::cout << "Milliseconds: " << duration * 1000 << std::endl;
```

To use C++11 in GCC, you run `g++ -std=c++11 -o app main.cpp`. For the Visual Studio compiler, you need 2012 or higher to use chrono.